# Information on what .captain.picard * #riker means for CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm wondering what .captain.picard * #riker means. I'm pretty sure it means that any HTML element with class "captain picard" (a div for example) has everything inside it selected, and then in that everything selected all html elements with id "riker" are selected and styled. For example:

```
<div class="captain picard">
  <p id="riker">One</p>
  <p id="pikespeak">Two</p>
  <p id="peakout">Three</p>
</div>

.captain.picard * #riker {
  color: red;
}
```

Then the word One should be styled, red, right? Doesn't happen. I'm confused as to why this is... if I take away the #riker selector, then all the tags word are styled red which makes complete sense. Can anybody help?

Comment: Why you want to use `*` ? any specifics? and you can directly target without that as well `captain.picard  #riker {color: red};`

Comment: the * means 'each element', so don't need to put that if you're only selecting #riker one.

Comment: @Deepak Yadav: Read the first paragraph.

Comment: I agree with you in that this is *highly* impractical, but this is for an HTML exercise and assuming that that selector cannot be modified, what would it actually be selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove *, that means 'all elements'. Look how it works

```css
.captain.picard #riker {
  color: red;
}

.captain.picard2 * {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="captain picard">
  <p id="riker">One</p>
  <p id="pikespeak">Two</p>
  <p id="peakout">Three</p>
</div>

<div class="captain picard2">
  <p id="rike2r">One</p>
  <p id="pikespeak2">Two</p>
  <p id="peakout2">Three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to removed the * as it stands for every possible element which would be between the element with the class and the id

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty sure it means that any HTML element with class "captain picard" (a div for example) has everything inside it selected, and then in that everything selected all html elements with id "riker" are selected and styled.

That would be either `.captain.picard *#riker` (notice the space *after* the `*` is omitted), or just `.captain.picard #riker`.

Separating the `*` and id selector with a space represents *two different elements*, with the `*` being the ancestor. Add that to `.captain.picard` (and its descendant combinator) and you have *three* levels of nesting, which doesn't match the structure here.

Answer (score 0):

oky lets be clear if you want to style only one div item you don't need to use *

simply use

```
  .captain  #riker {
  color: red;
  }
```

one class selector is fine

```
.picard  #riker {
 color: red;
  }
```

will do the same

but if you want to select all the elements under captain class then you can use *
for example

```
.captain  * {
color: green;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By using class like this
 **.captain.picard  #riker** what you have said can be accomplished i.e., within class '.captain.picard' all the id with  '#riker' changes as per style given.

```css
.captain.picard  #riker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="captain picard">
  <p id="riker">One</p>
  <p id="pikespeak">Two</p>
  <p id="peakout">Three</p>
  <p id="riker">four</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
<div class="captain picard">
  <p id="riker">One</p>
  <p id="pikespeak">Two</p>
  <p id="peakout">Three</p>
</div>
```

When CSS is: `.captain.picard *` it goes till **piecard** and then targets **all** selectors below it. If this is written - everything below will be in red color.

[image: Red color text]

// When CSS is: `.captain.picard * #riker` it goes till **piecard** and then targets **all** selectors below it and tries to find #riker as a child of all but doesn't finds one. Hence no red.

[image: No color change]

But, as per your CSS.
When `.captain.picard * #riker` it goes till **piecard** and then targets **all** selectors below it and tries to find **#riker** as a child of all (in this case, **.something**).
It finds **#riker** in child of `*`
Hence Color is Red:

or you could target is as `.captain.picard *#riker`
But you could easily do this without adding `*` as well.

Simply:
you wrote 3 level of CSS hierarchy (because you added `space` after `*` and before `#riker`), but in HTML - there are only two level hierarchy. Unless you add an intermediate level in your HTML, your css won't get its target.

```css
.captain.picard * #riker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="captain picard">
  <div class="something">
    <p id="riker">One</p>
  </div>
  <p id="pikespeak">Two</p>
  <p id="peakout">Three</p>
</div>
```